# How do I fix my Java code so that it ends when a user types "quit"?

Tags: java, loops, calculator, quit

So I have been working on this simple calculator in Java for a while now, and I want the program to end when a user types "quit" in the scanner. I tried to implement this feature as an 'If' statement near the end of my main class in the following line:

```
if (input.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for using my program.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

My IDE doesn't recognize any errors, but when I compile and run my program, and attempt to exit the program by typing 'quit' into the scanner, the program ends (with errors) without displaying my exit message.

My code is as follows:

```
 package calculator;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello, welcome to my calculator");
        System.out.println("Enter in some stuff you want to me to calculate");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("If you need help please type \"help\"");
        System.out.println("If at anytime you want to leave, type \"quit\"");
        System.out.println("If you want to continue, hit enter.");

        String s1 = scan.nextLine();

        if (s1.equals("help")){
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Double operand commands:");
            System.out.println("Addition: '+' (Ex: 'a + b' )");
            System.out.println("Subtraction: '-' (Ex: 'a - b' )");
            System.out.println("Multiplication: '*' (Ex: 'a * b' ) ");
            System.out.println("Division: '/' (Ex: 'a / b' )");
            System.out.println("Exponents: '^' (Ex: 'a ^ b' )");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Maths maths = new Maths();

        double answer = 0;
        double numA, numB;
        char operator;
        boolean quit = false;

         while (quit == false) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your equation: ");

            numA = input.nextDouble();
            operator = input.next().charAt(0);
            numB = input.nextDouble();        

            if (operator == '+') {
                answer = maths.add(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '-') {
                answer = maths.subtract(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '*') {
                answer = maths.multiply(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '/') {
                answer = maths.divide(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '^') {
                answer = maths.power(numA, numB);
            }

            System.out.println(answer);        

        if (input.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println("Thanks for using my program.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

         }       

        input.close();

        }

    }

    class Maths {

        double add(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a+b;
            return answer;          
        }

        double subtract(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a-b;
            return answer;          
        }

        double multiply(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a*b;
            return answer;          
        }

        double divide(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a/b;
            return answer;          
        }

        double power(double a, double b){
            double answer =a;

            for (int x=2; x<=b; x++){
                answer *= a;
            }

            return answer;
        }

    }
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me what's wrong so that my code will finally work and so that I won't make a similar mistake in the future!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `input`? What do you think `input.equals("quit")` does?

Comment: what is your exit message?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think it means "if the user types in quit, then do something"

Comment: @getlost "Thank you for using my program", and then the program should end...without any errors

Comment: `input` is a variable of type `Scanner`. Will a `Scanner` object ever be equal to a `String` object? What you want to do is get input from the `Scanner` and compare that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry for the lame question...I am a high schooler just getting started practicing Java...but how would you go about doing what you said?

Comment: The Scanner class has a bunch of method for getting user input, some of which you are already using. Use one to retrieve the word "quit" at the appropriate time.

Comment: @AhadSheriff do you want to exit the programe from anytime?when user type operater if use type quit instead operator do you want to exit?

Comment: @getlost yes, I want to exit the program from anytime, sorry but I didn't understand the second part of your question!

Comment: @AhadSheriff take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually your boolean quit is redundant in this case.

all you need to do is change loop to `while (true){}` and exit if user enter "`quit`". take a look this code.

don't call `nextDouble();`  take first input as a String and check is it quit or not.if not then you can covert it to double using `Double.parseInt()` otherwise a number-format exception will be thrown  and if  user input is "quit" you can call `system.exit(0);` but also you can call `return;`

```
package calculator;

 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello, welcome to my calculator");
        System.out.println("Enter in some stuff you want to me to calculate");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("If you need help please type \"help\"");
        System.out.println("If at anytime you want to leave, type \"quit\"");
        System.out.println("If you want to continue, hit enter.");

        String s1 = scan.nextLine();

        if (s1.equals("help")){
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Double operand commands:");
            System.out.println("Addition: '+' (Ex: 'a + b' )");
            System.out.println("Subtraction: '-' (Ex: 'a - b' )");
            System.out.println("Multiplication: '*' (Ex: 'a * b' ) ");
            System.out.println("Division: '/' (Ex: 'a / b' )");
            System.out.println("Exponents: '^' (Ex: 'a ^ b' )");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Maths maths = new Maths();

        double answer = 0;
        double numA, numB;
        char operator;
        boolean quit = false;


         while (true) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your equation: ");
            String s=input.next();
            if(s.equals("quit")){
                System.out.println("Thanks for using my programe");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            numA = Double.parseDouble(s);
            operator = input.next().charAt(0);
            numB = input.nextDouble();        

            if (operator == '+') {
                answer = maths.add(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '-') {
                answer = maths.subtract(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '*') {
                answer = maths.multiply(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '/') {
                answer = maths.divide(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '^') {
                answer = maths.power(numA, numB);
            }

            System.out.println(answer);        



         }

        }

    }

    class Maths {

        double add(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a+b;
            return answer;          
        }

        double subtract(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a-b;
            return answer;          
        }

        double multiply(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a*b;
            return answer;          
        }

        double divide(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a/b;
            return answer;          
        }

        double power(double a, double b){
            double answer =a;

            for (int x=2; x<=b; x++){
                answer *= a;
            }

            return answer;
        }
}
```

sample output >>

```
Hello, welcome to my calculator
Enter in some stuff you want to me to calculate
If you need help please type "help"
If at anytime you want to leave, type "quit"
If you want to continue, hit enter.

Please enter your equation: 2
+
3
5.0
Please enter your equation: quit
Thanks for using my programe
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the boolean quit to true in your if statement when the user types quit so it will exit the while loop.

Comment: 'if (input.equals("quit")) {
        boolean quit = true;
    }'

Comment: just try  if (input.equals("quit")) { quit = true; }'

Comment: you already declared the boolean quit, so you don't need to declare it again.  If the user types "quit" then the quit will be true and will not satisfy the quit == false in your while condition, it will then exit the loop.

Comment: Also I don't think that's how you should use While statement. I think you should use if and elseif statement for being a beginner. And for proper tracking of error you should always use system.out.println("Something is wrong here") . This way you know what part of program is not working

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an InputMismatchException because you're giving the scanner a string when its expecting a double.

String variables should be read in using the `scanner.nextLine()` method.

See, once this is displayed:

```
Hello, welcome to my calculator
Enter in some stuff you want to me to calculate
If you need help please type "help"
If at anytime you want to leave, type "quit"
If you want to continue, hit enter.
```

Your code goes into the while loop, which doesn't support string input.
What you could do is add a print statement asking for user input("help","quit", or enter")
and proceed based on that.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that Scanner cannot use the .equals method. You need to first identify a string variable, set it equal to Scanner.ReadLine(), and then compare that to the "quit" string. Something like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String input = scan.ReadLine();

if(input.equals("quit"))
{
   //close the program
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Are you confusing Scanner with Console from c#?

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure this will work. You can't compare a scanner variable to a string variable.

Comment: If you copied and pasted my code, it won't work for you.

Comment: If the solution you provided can't be used, then why post it?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because of the cache. You could do the flush before system exit.